# getListView() replacement when using RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am implementing Material Design in my app and converting ListViews to RecyclerViews.  I have been following tutorials which used the method getListView() but these are no longer available when I extend my class with AppCompatActivity.  Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: getListView() method is available for ListActivity , ListFragment which returns the list view. To replace such instances simply place recyclerview in AppCompatActivity and use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getListView()` is a convenience method on `ListActivity` and `ListFragment`. There is no requirement to use `ListActivity` or `ListFragment` to use a `ListView`, however. If you use a regular `Activity` or a regular `Fragment`, you would retrieve your `ListView` from your layout using `findViewById()`, as you would with any other sort of widget.

The same holds true for `RecyclerView`. You will retrieve the `RecyclerView` from your inflated layout using `findViewById()`.

Now, you are welcome to create your own `RecyclerViewActivity` and `RecyclerViewFragment` that you can extend, if you wish. For example, you could have a `RecyclerViewActivity` like this:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2015 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain    a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.recyclerview.simplelist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class RecyclerViewActivity extends Activity {
  private RecyclerView rv=null;

  public void setAdapter(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
    getRecyclerView().setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  public RecyclerView.Adapter getAdapter() {
    return(getRecyclerView().getAdapter());
  }

  public void setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.LayoutManager mgr) {
    getRecyclerView().setLayoutManager(mgr);
  }

  public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() {
    if (rv==null) {
      rv=new RecyclerView(this);
      rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
      setContentView(rv);
    }

    return(rv);
  }
}
```

Here, you can use `getRecyclerView()`, and `RecyclerViewActivity` will create the `RecyclerView` instance for you and set it as the content view of the activity. While in my case, `RecyclerViewActivity` inherits from `Activity`, changing it to inherit from `AppCompatActivity` is a matter of adding 9 characters to the base class (`Activity` --> `AppCompatActivity`).

Comment: Thank-you @CommonsWare. I understand this now.